# What is the best practice for maintaining large assets in a project?

Tags: asp.net, version-control

We have a project which involves some extremely large (multi-gig) video files. Keeping this in source control slows everything down, especially when performing a build. It seems to me that source control is not the right place for these assets, as they are more akin to data in the database than code.

Still, they are IP and need to be properly maintained. Does anyone have experience in managing these assets in a way that provides the safety that we need but doesn't muck up source control / the build?

Comment: Is it simply static data which is consumed by your application or is it really an item which is up for change and therefore you want to store it in source control for versioning, history lookups, branch/merge strategies, etc.?

Comment: Pretty static. Definitely nothing that is subject to merging...

Answer (score 1):

I would simply keep them in a seperate source control repo and include instructions in the directory where they reside on where to checkout from

Comment: A separate repo sounds like a sensible solution! Because his video files rarely change, I would create a separate deployment pipeline for the video repo. For all testing environmetns I would include these files into the image/snapshot and on production you can actually deploy it with your application.